# discord.py client.say @user only using ctx argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Using:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def bla(ctx):
```

I want to add a `await client.say` that could @ the user. I have been trying to use the `(ctx.message.author))` but the I only got this printed in the Discord server: [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzWBT.png)

*Code used in image above:* `await client.say("Bla bla bla! @{}".format(ctx.message.author))`

I don't want to add another argument to the `async def bla(ctx):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.mention) attribute of the `author` object.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def bla(ctx):
    await client.say("Bla bla bla! {}".format(ctx.message.author.mention))
```